# 12V DC Switch Connection?

Tags: switches

I have a 12V and 20A LED switch,but I want to switch 24V DC with this switch.Is it possible to turn on the LED on the switch and also switch 24V DC?
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: It will certainly also switch at 24V.

Comment: Will the LED on it illuminate?

Comment: Yes, the LED will also light up.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet or link for this switch?

Comment: Sorry datasheet does not exist.When the switch is in the 'ON' position, the (+) and the LED pin are shorted.So wouldn't it be ridiculous to give 12V to the LED pin and give 24V to the (+) leg?

Answer (score 2):

24 V switching may damage the switch contacts if you are switching high current and particularly if the load is highly inductive.

24 V will probably pass too much current through the LED so you would require an external series resistor on the LED terminal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn4051.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The safest option is to measure the current drawn on a 12 V supply and add a series resistor to drop 12 V at that current.

[Hellas Digital](https://www.hellasdigital.gr/electronics/components/toggle-switch/illuminated-toggle-switch-with-cover-yellow/?sl=en) says

> Since there's an LED inside, but only 3 pin, they're a little different to wire than most toggle switches.
>
> - The anode (positive side) of the LED is connected through a resistor to the pin with a 'headlamp' (=D) symbol on it
> - The cathode (negative side) of the LED is connected to the pin with the ground symbol, which is the pin that is sticking out the side of the switch.
> - The switch connects and disconnects the (+) pin and the 'headlamp' pin
>
> That means you have a few options for wiring:
>
> - If you want to use the switch to turn on/off something, you can use the toggle to connect and disconnect the two pins on the bottom
> - If you want the LED to always be on, provide 3-12V between the ground and headlamp pin
> - If you want the LED to be on only when the switch is connected, provide 3-12V on the (+) pin and connect ground to the ground pin.
>
> The protective cover will automatically turn the switch off when flipped closed, but you can simply remove it if it isn't desired.